# Rails Show Age in View based Born Date

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, date-arithmetic

I have a problem to show age in a view with rails

i think this to solve:

```
 show.html.slim    
    `=@people.date_born - Date.today / 365,25`  
    `end`
```

What i need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably just an order of operations thing, but your syntax was displayed funny.  Ignoring the unnecessary quotes:

```
= ((Date.today - @person.date_born) / 365).to_i
```

First, since today is a greater date than the date of birth, you want it first to avoid a negative number.   You need to wrap it in parens to do the subtraction first, and then divide, and for legibility, change it back to an integer.